# Why does Java accept a "return null" for a function prototype with the return type "Character" but not for the return type "char"?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm refreshing my knowledge of Java and I was working with a function that I set with a return type of `char` and then I had a `return null` statement in the function but Eclipse began complaining. As soon as I replaced the return type of `char` with `Character` instead, it started working.

I understand Character is a wrapper class for the primitive type char and so I can understand how the Character class may be able to accept a null and return that "null object" whereas a primitive char has no means of representing a null. But I have no idea if this conjecture is true and if it is true, I was wondering if someone could enlighten me on the details or point me in the right direction.

Comment: because Character is an encapsulated `class` and char is just a primitive type, which tells the disparity. `instance` can have null value, whereas primitive dont

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is an object, and therefore `null` is an acceptable value for a `Character` reference.

A `char` is a [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), and can't be assigned the value `null`.

Comment: So is what I guessed more or less correct? I just want to make sure there are no logical inconsistencies in my reasoning.

Comment: @You are completely on track and what you are thinking is right.

Comment: @eddieberklee: Yes, your reasoning is correct. You can read more about the two variants in the links I provided.

Answer (score 3):

> how the Character class may be able to accept a null and return that "null object" whereas a primitive char has no means of representing a null.

Only Objects can hold a `null`  value. Since char is a [`primitive type`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) it has its own default value and you can't assign a `null` to it where as Character is an Object , you can assign `null`

Objects default is `null`

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte                     0
short                    0
int                      0
long                     0L
float                    0.0f
double                   0.0d
**char**               '\u0000'
**String (or any object)**  null
boolean false
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Character` is an `Object` hence `null` is allowed. The primitive type `char` is assigned a default value.

- As the `Character` is an `Object`, it is comprised of a reference
  variable and an Object. If any object is not assigned to reference
  variable, it does not refer anything i.e. `null`
- In case of the `char` primitive always a default value is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

`Character` inherits `Object` class and Object null can be a `Character`.
whereas `char` is a primitive

Answer (score 0):

A primitive wrapper class in the Java and ActionScript programming languages is one of eight classes provided in the java.lang package to provide object methods for the eight primitive types. All of the primitive wrapper classes in Java are immutable. J2SE 5.0 introduced autoboxing of primitive types into their wrapper object, and automatic unboxing of the wrapper objects into their primitive value—the implicit conversion between the wrapper objects and primitive values.
Wrapper classes are used to represent primitive values when an Object is required. The wrapper classes are used extensively with Collection classes in the java.util package and with the classes in the java.lang.reflect reflection package.
The primitive wrapper classes and their corresponding primitive types are:

---

Primitive  type ->  Wrapper class ->    Constructor Arguments

1. byte ->  Byte    -> byte or String
2. short -> Short ->    short or String
3. int  ->  Integer  ->int or String
4. long ->  Long -> long or String
5. float -> Float    -> float, double or String
6. double ->    Double   -> double or String
7. char ->  Character    ->char
8. boolean ->   Boolean ->  boolean or String

---

The Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float, and Double wrapper classes are all subclasses of the Number class.
The wrapper classes BigDecimal and BigInteger are not one of the primitive wrapper classes and are mutable.

see also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

So in conclusion objects(Character) can be assigned the null value in Java but primitive (char) cannot since they denote a location in memory having on value, but primitives are references for a memory location containing the whole class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CharacterDemo {

    private static char a;

    private static Character b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           //default value
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

When you execute the above code 
Output:

null

In the first line it prints null character '\u0000'
but second line it prints null object
```

Comment: object.toString() is printed in second line